# Displaying output after adding item to list

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
    import time,sys,random
wpm = 125
userName = ""
global mirror 
mirror = False
global knife
knife = False
inventory = []
vial = False
trollHit = 0
playerHit = 0
axe = False
choice2 = False
kitchenAlready = False
def death():
  sys.exit()

userInput = ""

def cantPerformAction(userInput):
  if userInput == "e" or userInput == "u" or userInput == "w" or userInput == "s" or "t" in userInput:
    slow_type("You can't perform that action.")


def checkDirection(userInput):
  if any(char in userInput for char in 'nsewudt') == False:
    return False
  elif any(char in userInput for char in 'nsewudt') == True:
    return True

#credit to 'bill gross' for ideas on the slow type 
def slow_type(y): #slow typing to make it seem like the computer is typing
  for x in y:
    sys.stdout.write(x)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(random.random(     )*10.0/wpm)
  print (' ')

def clear(): #clear the line so that another line of text can appear below it
  print ("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")



#CROSSROADS: All directions lead to death except right. Player cannot turn back.

def crossroads():
  slow_type("\n\nCrossroads")
  slow_type("\n\nA crossroads is in front of you. There is a passage to the west, east, and north.")


  global choice2
  global choice
  choice = None
  choice2 = None
  youBetterChoose = 0
  while choice == None and choice2 == None:
    userInput = input("\n>")
    if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      while checkDirection == False:
        userInput = input("\n>")
        checkDirection(userInput)
    userInput1 = userInput.lower().strip()
    if userInput1 == "s":
      clearingalready()
    if userInput1 =="n":
      slow_type("\n>You walk forward, determined... off a cliff. Tragic!")
      death()
    if userInput1 == "w":
      slow_type("\nYou encounter a giant spider. Without a weapon, it easily tears you to shreds.")
      death()
    if userInput1 == "e":
      fork()
    if userInput1 == "d":
      slow_type("You can't do down farther than the floor.")
    if userInput1 == "u":
      slow_type("You can't go that way.")

  userInput = ""

def crossroadsalready():
  slow_type("\n\nCrossroads")

  global choice2
  global choice
  choice = None
  choice2 = None
  youBetterChoose = 0
  while choice == None and choice2 == None:
    userInput = input("\n>")
    if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      while checkDirection == False:
        userInput = input("\n>")
        checkDirection(userInput)
    userInput1 = userInput.lower().strip()
    if userInput1 == "s":
      clearingalready()
    if userInput1 =="n":
      slow_type("\n>You walk forward, determined... off a cliff. Tragic!")
      death()
    if userInput1 == "w":
      slow_type("\nYou encounter a giant spider. Without a weapon, it easily tears you to shreds.")
      death()
    if userInput1 == "e":
      fork()
    if userInput1 == "d":
      slow_type("You can't do down farther than the floor.")
    if userInput1 == "u":
      slow_type("You can't go that way.")

  userInput = ""

def fork():
  choice2 = False
  slow_type("\nFork")
  slow_type("\nThere are another two ways to go. One goes north into a cavern, another leads down deeper into the earth.\n\n")
  deeperOrFarther = ""
  while choice2 == False:
    userInput = input(">")
    checkDirection(userInput)
    if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      while checkDirection(userInput) == False:
        userInput = input (">")
        checkDirection(userInput)
    deepLower = userInput.lower().strip()
    if deepLower == "n":
      slow_type("You walk forward, determined... off a cliff. Tragic!")
      choice2 = True
      death()
    if deepLower == "d":
      slow_type("You descend down into the darker regions of the cave.")
      choice2 = True
    if deepLower == "w":
      crossroadsalready()
    cantPerformAction(deepLower)
  houseChoice()

wpm = 60    
slow_type("Welcome to Zotan! \nn = north \ns = south \nw = west \ne = east \nu = up \nd = down \nt = take")
clear()
wpm = 120

def clearing():
  slow_type("Clearing\n")
  slow_type("You wake up in the middle of a clearing. There is a passage to the north.")
  slow_type("\n\n")
  clearingalready = True


  choice = None

  while choice == None:
    userInput = input("\n>")
    if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      while checkDirection == False:
        userInput = input("\n>")
        checkDirection(userInput)
    userInput = userInput.lower()
    if userInput.strip() == "n":
      choice = False
    else:
      slow_type("You can't go that way.")
  userInput = ""
  crossroads() #1

def clearingalready():
  slow_type("Clearing\n")
  slow_type("There is a passage to the north.")
  slow_type("\n\n")

  choice = None

  while choice == None:
    userInput = input("\n>")
    if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      while checkDirection == False:
        userInput = input("\n>")
        checkDirection(userInput)
    userInput = userInput.lower()
    if userInput.strip() == "n":
      choice = False
    else:
      slow_type("You can't go that way.")
  userInput = ""
  crossroads() #1

def houseChoice():
  slow_type("\n\n\n\nHouse Doorway\n\n")
  choice = None
  while choice == None:
    userInput = input(">")
    checkDirection(userInput)
    if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      while checkDirection(userInput) == False:
        userInput = input(">")
        checkDirection(userInput)

    userInput = userInput.lower().strip()
    if userInput == "d" or userInput == "u"  or userInput == "w" or userInput == "e":
      slow_type("You can't go that way.")
    if userInput == "n":
      choice = False
    if userInput == "s":
      choice = False
  if userInput == "s":
    fork() 
  elif userInput == "n":
    entryway()

def entryway():
  slow_type("\nEntryway")
  slow_type("\n\nThere is a kitchen to the west and a dark staircase. A back door hangs open in the north, revealing the entry into another dark corridor.")
  userInput = input("\n>")
  if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
    while checkDirection == False:
      userInput = input("\n>")
      checkDirection(userInput)
  userInput = userInput.lower().strip()
  if userInput == "w":
    kitchen()
  if userInput == "u":
    attic()
  if userInput == "n":
    chasm()#4
  if userInput == "s":
    houseChoice()

def entrywayalready():
  slow_type("\nEntryway")
  userInput = input("\n>")
  if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
    while checkDirection == False:
      userInput = input("\n>")
      checkDirection(userInput)
  userInput = userInput.lower().strip()
  if userInput == "w":
    if kitchenAlready == False:
     kitchen()
    elif kitchenAlready == True:
      kitchenalready()
  if userInput == "u":
    attic()
  if userInput == "n":
    chasm()#4

def kitchen():
  kitchenAlready = True
  slow_type("\n\nKitchen")
  slow_type("It seems that the kitchen has been used recently. There is a wicked looking steak knife on the counter, and a mirror on the table.")
  userInput = input("\n>")
  userInput = userInput.lower().strip()
  if userInput == "t knife":
    if "knife" not in inventory:
      slow_type("Taken.")
      inventory.append("knife")
    elif "knife" in inventory:
      slow_type("You can't take that item.")
  elif userInput == "t mirror":
    if "mirror" not in inventory:
      inventory.append("mirror")
    elif "mirror" in inventory:
      slow_type("You can't take that item.")
    slow_type("You can't perform that action.")
  elif userInput == "e":
    entrywayalready()


def kitchenalready():
  slow_type("\n\nKitchen")
  userInput = input("\n>")
  userInput = userInput.lower().strip()
  if "knife" not in inventory:
      inventory.append("knife")
  elif "knife" in inventory:
      slow_type("You can't take that item.")
  if userInput == "t mirror":
    if "mirror" not in inventory:
      inventory.append("mirror")
    elif "mirror" in inventory:
      slow_type("You can't take that item.")
  if userInput == "e":
    entrywayalready()

def attic():
  slow_type("\n\nAttic")
  choice = None
  while choice == None:
    userInput = input(">")
    if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      while checkDirection == False:
        userInput = input(">")
        checkDirection(userInput)
    userInput = userInput.lower().strip()
    if userInput == "n" or userInput == "s" or userInput == "e" or userInput == "w" or userInput == "u":
      slow_type("You can't go that way")
    if userInput == "t vial":
      if "vial" not in inventory:
        slow_type("Taken.")
        inventory.append("vial")
      elif "vial" in inventory:
        slow_type("You can't take that item.")
    if userInput == "d":
      choice = False

  entryway()#6

def chasm():
  slow_type("\n\nChasm")
  slow_type("\nThere is a chasm in front of you, with a rickety wooden bridge crossing the wide and endlessly deep ravine to the north, and a small passage to the west.")
  userInput = input(">")
  checkDirection(userInput)
  if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
    while checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      userInput = input (">")
      checkDirection(userInput)
  chasmChoice = userInput.lower().strip()
  if chasmChoice == "n":
    slow_type("You cross the wooden bridge and it crumbles behind you. There is no turning back.")
    cavern()
  if chasmChoice == "w":
    smallPassage()
  if chasmChoice == "s":
    entryway()#7

def smallPassage():
  slow_type("\n\nSmall Passage")
  slow_type("\nThere is a room to the west.")
  userInput = input(">")
  checkDirection(userInput)
  if checkDirection(userInput) == False:
    while checkDirection(userInput) == False:
      userInput = input (">")
      checkDirection(userInput)
  userInputLower = userInput.lower().strip()
  if userInputLower == "w":
    trollRoom()
  if userInputLower == "e":
    chasm()
  if userInputLower == "s" or userInputLower == "n" or userInputLower == "u" or userInputLower == "d" or userInputLower == "t":
    slow_type("You can't perform that action.")#8

def trollRoom():
  slow_type("\n\nTroll Room")
  slow_type("\nThere is a troll in the room with a large blood stained axe.")
  lowerr = "l"
  while lowerr != "e":
    userInput = input(">")
    lowerr = userInput.lower().strip()
    if lowerr == "attack troll":
      if "knife" in inventory:
        xRan = random.randint(0,3)
        if xRan == "3":
          slow_type("The troll parries your attack.")
        if xRan == "2":
          slow_type("You get a clear hit on the troll. It groans loudly, displaying a look of deep hatred on it's deformed face.")
          trollHit = trollHit + 1
          if trollHit == 2:
            slow_type("The troll falls to the floor, dead. Its axe lays on the floor.")
            axe = True
            if userInput != "t axe" or userInput != "e":
              slow_type("You can't perform that action.")
        if xRan == 3:
          if playerHit == 0:
            slow_type("The troll knocks you back.")
          if playerHit == 1:
            slow_type("The troll lands a clean graze on your shoulder. You cry out in pain.")
    if lowerr == "t axe":
      if axe == True:
        slow_type("Taken.")
        inventory.append("axe")
      elif axe != True:
        slow_type("There is no axe there.")
    if lowerr == "n" or lowerr == "s" or lowerr == "d" or lowerr == "u" or lowerr == "t" or lowerr == "w":
      slow_type("You cannot perform that action.")#9




clearingAlready = False #Determines whether or not the player has already been to the crossroads.

clearing()
crossroads()
fork()
```

When I execute this particular part of the code It seems like there is no ouput from the computer, no `Taken.` or `You can't perform that action`. I can't seem to pinpoint the exact cause of the error or why it is misbehaving.

Console output:

```
    House Doorway
>n
Entryway

>w

Kitchen

>t knife

output: nothing
```

Comment: Please show a sample run of this code. I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with it, so your input is crucial here.

Comment: Also consider writing a separate function to take an item since you use identical code twice.

Comment: Also, consider making all `userInput == ...` checks except `t knife` be in an `elif` instead of a plain `if`.

Comment: it's in a file with many other functions. When I type "t knife" when the input nothing is displayed.

Comment: Can you print the relevant portion of a sample session? Place it into the question itself, not the comments please.

Comment: I am on a school computer running my code from a web python editor. Not sure how I'm going to be able to show you all my code, it's over 300 lines but if you insist

Comment: I don't want to see all your code. I just want to see a console output of you playing this portion of the game, with your inputs and outputs. Just a couple of lines before `Kitchen` and a couple of lines after the end so I can see the context where it failed.

Comment: console output added.